# My Application Crash when i get External Storage Access In Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

When I Ask to access all the files of the device it goes to the permission but when it allows the permission the app crashes can someone please help me with that!!The code where I ask for permission is Given Below:

The Error while it crasher is

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
> ResultInfo{who=null, request=210, result=0, data=null} to activity
> {savestatusgallery.download.waimage.savevideostatus.application/savestatusgallery.download.waimage.savevideostatus.application.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted

```
Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> result = await [
    Permission.storage,
    Permission.manageExternalStorage
    ].request();
```

I should get back to my app but it crashes Can you tell me what I can do

Comment: Can you share Android OS Version?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.